# Why can you only upvote a comment, and not downvote it?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined

A question and an answer can be both upvoted and downvoted. Why by a comment can you only upvote? What if I think it is wrong, why can I not downvote it?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but you might find some insight in [these](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3615/should-downvoting-be-allowed-on-comments) two [discussions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7014/ability-to-downvote-comments) on MSO.

Comment: Tagging this `status-declined` because of those discussions (one of which asks the same question and was so tagged by Jeff Atwood).

Answer (score 8):

Firstly, there are obviously others that agree with you (myself excluded). However, the current SO policy delineated [over here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3615/should-downvoting-be-allowed-on-comments/3620#3620) is that downvotes for comments will not be allowed/implemented.

The basic thought is that if you disagree with a comment, you should post a follow-up comment that says so (and thereby explains your disagreement). On the other hand, if you agree with a comment, we *really* don't want you leaving a comment saying "+1," "me too" or the like, so we let you upvote it.

Comment: What about down voting questions