# Comments - why is there no option to down vote?

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can you only upvote a comment, and not downvote it?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/352/why-can-you-only-upvote-a-comment-and-not-downvote-it)

On comments you can you only up vote or flag and not down vote.If I dislike the comment yet I see no reason to flag it - why can you not down vote it?

Comment: Great mind thinks alike! :)